# An adjective for something that has been achieved with a lot of effort through years

Tags: word-request, adjectives

I am looking for an adjective that describes something that has been achieved <s>hardly</s> after a lot of effort through years.

> For instance, **hardly-achieved** experience OR **hardly-gained** knowledge.

Is there any specific word for that?

**Edit:** By *hardly* I meant through hard and laborious work. It's not something rare. Anybody can achieve it, but only after a lot of hard work and effort through years.

Comment: You should ask this way then - **I'm looking for the adjective that describes our achievement through efforts of years**

Comment: http://www.confusing-words.com/?toload=inner.Body_ConfusingWords&id=4857&BereichID=134&title=+%3Ca+href%3D%3F%3EConfusing+Words%3C%2Fa%3E+%3E+&title2=hard+and+hardly

Comment: **hardly never means through hard/laborious work/efforts.** This question misleads and should be edited.

Comment: @MaulikV edited my question.

Comment: The question should read: **hard-achieved** and **hard-gained**. *Hardly* means not at all; scarcely; very rarely; as in "I hardly ever go to the cinema." and "He's so quiet, he hardly talks"

Comment: Overnight Success?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest *hard-won*, though this is not noticeably any better than *hard-gained* or *hard-earned*.

Note however that *hardly* should not be employed. *Hardly* usually means “just barely” or “almost not”  rather than “with difficulty”. It is therefore conventional with participles to employ *hard-*,  hyphenated, to express the meaning “with difficulty”.

Comment: *hardly* in other sense works though. As I said, *hardly achieved record* will imply to something that's too difficult to achieve. I know *hardly* creates an ambiguity here and that's why I recommended *rarely/barely* for that

Comment: @MaulikV "hardly" is not ambiuguous: it only means "barely" and is never used to mean "in a hard way". A "hardly achieved record" would be an unusual way of talking about a record that was only just achieved: for example, shaving one second off the marathon time.

Comment: In fact "hardly" also means "not truly": "his good reputation is hardly deserved". You can't have a not-achieved record, if it wasn't achieved it's not a record. But otherwise a hardly-achieved record could mean one that in fact was not achieved at all.

Answer (score 9):

There is a commonly used term, **[hard-earned](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/hard-earned)**, to convey this concept

> earned or achieved only after a lot of effort

Comment: -1. I disagree. the difference between *hard* and *hardly* lies there! *hard-earned money* - you do a lot of efforts and earn money. *hardly achieved record of diving from 40000 feet* - the record that is rarely/barely achieved. Of course, to achieve *hardly achieved record*, you need to have a *hard-work!*

Comment: @MaulikV The word *hardly* means *barely*. I do not think that is what the questioner intends.

Comment: Exactly. The record of finishing 100 meters in 6 seconds is  **barely/hardly** achieved by someone. In fact, that's what OP means. I edited the question though.

Comment: @MaulikV Are you sure? I took OP to mean *with difficulty*, which seems to suit better with "through years".

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, you are right, that's what I meant.

Comment: @StoneyB I think so. The OP means something that's hardly ever acheived/gained/experienced. Okay, in such case, we shall ask OP or vote for 'unclear'.

Comment: @MaulikV No, the record of finishing 100m in 6s is not achieved at all! (At least, not by running.)

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for the word **painstaking**.
"Painstaking" usually means "with much time, effort and attention".

For example, "Building a ship was a painstaking endeavour".

Answer (score 2):

I **toiled over** this answer for quite a bit! I only came up with an idiom.